# The meaning of しないでもなかった

Tags: grammar, meaning, negation

> 彼の性格が読めてきたような気がしないでもなかった

しない is a negative conjugation of する

And from what I understand でもなかった is the equivalent of "was not"

So it's a double denial? How does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, しないでもない (≒しなくもない） is a double-negative construction, which can be seen as a set phrase used to say something less confidently, or to reluctantly admit something.

> 彼の性格が読めてきたような気がしないでもなかった
>   (lit.) It was not that I didn't feel I came to be able to read his character.
>   I feel I have gradually learnt how to understand his character.

Similar examples:

> - 失敗だったと言えなくもない。　≒　失敗だったと言えないでもない。
>     (lit.) It is not that one cannot say it was a failure.
>     One could argue that it was a failure.
> - 100万円はなくもない。　≒　100万円はないでもない。
>     (lit.) It is not that I don't have one million yen.
>     (Admittedly,) I have one million yen.